# Ruby on Rails crontab task is scheduled but not running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake-task, whenever

I am using the whenever gem to create the rake task, i am expecting to get a line output **"Teaching Thabo how to schedule tasks"** on my terminal every 2 minutes, i am new to Rails, here is the code for my rake task file which i have named request_invoice.rake

```
 namespace :request_invoice do
  desc "Teaching Thabo how to schedule tasks"
  task test_tasking: :environment do
  puts "Learning the tasking in rails..."
  end
 end
```

And the whenever gem created a schedule.rb file in the config of my project, i have the following code in the file

```
 every 2.minutes do
 rake 'request_invoice:test_tasking'
 end
```

I have ran the whenever command on the terminal, it gives the following:

```
    0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,5 2,54,56,58 /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/sable/GMS/grading-     management-solution && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake    request_invoice:test_tasking --silent'
## [message] Above is your schedule file converted to cron syntax; your crontab file was not updated.
## [message] Run `whenever --help' for more options.
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you run the:

```
whenever --update-crontab
```

command? According to the [gem's page](https://github.com/javan/whenever), this is required for your crontab file to be updated.

Comment: Yes i did run the whenever --update-crontab it gave back this :                 [write] crontab file updated

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to check whether you have added tasks to `crontab` or not using:

```
crontab -e
```

If you do not see your task, then add it using:

```
whenever -i
```

You can track your cron jobs by setting a log file. Just add the following to the top of `config/schedule.rb`:

```
set :output, "log/cron_log.log"
```

Now, you should be able to check your cron logs (if `tail` is available to you then do the following from the root of your application path):

```
tail -f log/cron_log.log
```

Comment: I can see the task , i even get the out put when i run it straight using rake, like rake request_envoice:test_tasking

Comment: did you type `crontab -e` , can you show the result ?

Comment: It opened up nano with this                                                                                                                                                                                  Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /home/sable/GMS/grading-management-solution/config/schedule.rb
0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58 * * * * /bin/b$

# End Whenever generated tasks for: /home/sable/GMS/grading-management-solution/config/schedule.rb

Comment: No just a blank nano with the above text at the beginning

Comment: Looks correct, check your cron log. Refer: https://github.com/javan/whenever/wiki/Output-redirection-aka-logging-your-cron-jobs

Comment: I have referred to the javan/whenever in GitHub and in works! I appreciate it guys.